# Run PL/SQL in the background and display a progress bar

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I wrote a package to import data from excel file to database with apex_data_parser
Some files may be heavy. I want a progress bar to start filling when the user is waiting for the operation to be done until the file is imported.
How can I create this progress bar?

In the code I wrote, I have the total number of rows, and the information is inserted line by line in the table And also that I installed a plugin that is called with javascript code in this way and it works.

```
apexProgressBar('P20_PROGRESS_BAR').setValues({percentage: 20, message: "Loading...", duration: 1000});
```

Now, how can I set this duration dynamically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is very clear what I want. I want to have a progress bar on my page in apex When pl/sql codes are executed, this progress bar will be filled.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I see it.

A PL/SQL procedure runs in the database and doesn't (can't) interact with end user. That's why - for example - "debugging" with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE isn't useful as procedure displays all messages at once, when procedure finishes its job.

Therefore, one option is to include logging into that procedure. You'd create additional table and autonomous transaction procedure which would insert log records into that table. Commit within won't affect the caller, but you can - in another session (read: your Apex application) - fetch from it and see how far you've come.

However, that's not useful if loading procedure works on the whole data set; you can log start and end, but nothing in between. It means that you should "split" loading into several pieces. Can't tell which ones; for example, loading itself, parsing, calculating, inserting into target table, whatever.

Another option is to use row-by-row processing (in a loop), but that's usually slow-by-slow, especially if you have to deal with a lot of data.
Maybe you could split that huge file into several smaller ones, or fetch data in chunks (for example, 50.000 rows in a set).

Certainly, you should know total number of rows - otherwise, how would you display progress bar. 10% of ... how much, exactly?

So, maybe you can, and maybe you can't do that. Difficult to tell.

Comment: In the code I wrote, I have the total number of rows, and the information is inserted line by line in the table
And also that I installed a plugin that is called with javascript code in this way and it works.
apexProgressBar('P20_PROGRESS_BAR').setValues({percentage: 20, message: "Loading...", duration: 1000});
Now, how can I set this duration dynamically?

Comment: What plugin are you using? This info might help to answer your question.